# What sort of goods or resources does a Federation Star Ship require to operate?

Tags: star-trek

I am making a game that is inspired heavily by Star Trek. The nature of the game requires that you are going about the Galaxy but are limited in some way, hopefully by resources.

But aside from the need for Dilithium Crystals, I can't think of any other resource in Star Trek that is required for a vessel to operate. Surely they must have some limitations on range and time away from a starbase?

Comment: Off the top of my head; antimatter, feedstock for replicators (or food if pre-TNG) and replacement crew. Also, presumably parts that are to bulky or complex to replicate with ease plus luxury items and living samples of things for the medical and arboriculture depts

Comment: Fresh pornographic holoprograms for Riker and the crew.

Comment: Refshirts! With enough redshirts, everything else is trivial.

Comment: On a more serious note, in Voyager it was always an issue how to get warp plasma, which I think is different from antimatter.

Comment: Semi-dupe of [How long can a galaxy class starship last before it needs servicing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53181/how-long-can-a-galaxy-class-starship-last-before-it-needs-servicing)

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Electro-plasma and https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Warp_core Warp Plasma is "created" by the matter/anti-matter reaction of the warp core, and the plasma is how energy is transported to the nacelles and other systems. I say "created" because I'm unclear if the warp core is actually creating plasma, or if the plasma already exists and is only being energized by the reaction. If they were constantly looking for it on Voyager, then it's probably the latter.

Comment: Also besides anti-matter (in the form of anti-deutronium), they'd also need deutronium, for the matter part of the matter/anti-matter reaction.

Comment: Thanks all for the info. Seems like I might need to rethink my approach.

Comment: A deck of playing cards, of course!

Comment: [Magnesite](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Magnesite) and [Anjoran bio-mimetic gel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Anjoran_bio-mimetic_gel) (*TNG* 7x21, ["Firstborn"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Firstborn_(episode))).

Comment: Whisky. The real stuff.